# How can Booth trust him?

Tags: plot-explanation, red-notice

Apologies for the weird title but I did not want to add spoilers. The actual title is

> How can Booth trust Hartley and Black at the end of the movie?

I understand the suspension of disbelief in such a movie but Booth has been constantly betrayed by Hartley (and Black). What can be his rationale for trusting them in the Louvre heist?

He had the upper hand on the boat because Das was coming, but this is over once they escaped her.

Answer (score 1):

> What can be his rationale for trusting them in the Louvre heist?

### What choice does he have?

He states that the job is..

> Double the payout, triple the challenge, plus, here's the best part.
>
> It's a three-thief job.

So he needs the best two people to pull it off.

Plus he's arrogant enough to believe that now that he knows they are working together he can make sure he's not tricked again.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that Hartley didn't double-cross Booth when he left the egg on the shore was probably the deciding factor in Booth trusting Hartley for the Louvre heist.

Comment: Well, he did double-cross him a few minutes later.